# SCCM (Real-Time Dashboard for Software Updates)

Tags: sccm

Do you know if there's any Dashboard on SCCM that would allow me to see in real time the status of the installation of patches when using Software Updates?

Something like this:

### Client  Status

YYY-CLI-01 | Downloading Update 1 of 37…

YYY-CLI-02 | Downloading Update 26 of 42…

YYY-CLI-03 | Installing Update 1 of 16…

YYY-CLI-04 | Rebooting…

YYY-CLI-05 | Complete

Thank you very much for your help and time!

Answer (score 3):

One of the things SCCM is not good at is real-time anything. I like SCCM but it's not a "real-time" solution for anything really. It requires the SCCM client side agent to gather info and send back to the server - that happens often and fast (usually) but not in real-time.

that said, Look at advertisement status web reports, and clicking into some of the links in those reports will get you slightly delayed status for a computer that is running an advertisement. Those are probably the reports I go to most.

Comment: +1 SCCM is purposely asynchronous, so real-time doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Via logs you can, but no dashboard to my knowledge.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892800.aspx

Look for "Software Update Point Log Files"

Answer (score 1):

The closest way to do this that I know of would be to use the [SCCM Dashboard](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff369719.aspx). It's not quite real-time but you can configure it to give you to give you an up to date report of update install statuses.

See the How Microsoft IT using Configuration Manager Dashboard? series on MSDN for some ideas and examples of what you can do with it [Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shitanshu/archive/2010/04/08/part-1-how-microsoft-it-using-configuration-manager-dashboard.aspx), [Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shitanshu/archive/2010/04/11/part-2-using-configuration-manager-dashboard-for-software-update-deployment-readiness-patch-tuesday-checklist.aspx), [Part 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shitanshu/archive/2010/05/02/part-3-sql-queries-used-for-creating-custom-configuration-manager-dashboard-in-microsoft-it.aspx) & [Part 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shitanshu/archive/2010/10/09/part-4-sql-queries-for-creating-configuration-manager-client-health-and-problem-management-dashboard.aspx).